# Is there a way for downloading arbitrary ranges from a GridFS collection's file using the mongocxx driver?

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I need random access to my files stored in a MongoDB using the GridFS specification. It seems that the C++ driver (mongocxx) doesn't provide an interface for doing that. I can create a `mongocxx::gridfs::downloader` object from a `mongocxx::gridfs::bucket`, however the only "lower level" read operation I can find is

`std::size_t read(std::uint8_t *buffer, std::size_t length)`

What I miss is a third parameter `std::size_t offset`. My current workaround is to circumvent the `mongocxx::gridfs` API completely, i.e., querying the chunks collection and creating the needed buffer manually. But I actually would like to use the driver's API for that.

Is there an API for my use case in the mongocxx driver that I didn't see or should I write a feature request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a closer look into all related sources and after discussing this question also in the [mongodb user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/smKcNRUduWo), the answer to this question is

No, by now there is no API for partial file retrieval using the GridFS API of the mongo C++ driver.

I have filed an a [feature request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CXX-1883) in the MongoDB JIRA system for it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is possible to do by manual iteration on chunks through c++ driver. You have to figure out which chunks contain this range of data, than read them and merge obtained data together...